# Print module signature of a file using Merlin

Tags: ocaml, bucklescript, merlin

Using Merlin 2.5.4, what is the correct way to print the signature of an OCaml file in my project? E.g., suppose I have:

```
(* foo.ml *)
let x = 1
```

And I want to get:

```
val x : int
```

What is the proper command (or sequence of commands)?

What I've tried:

I temporarily wrapped up the file in a submodule: `module Foo = struct let x = 1 end`, then ran:

```
$ ocamlmerlin
["type","expression","Foo","at",{"line":1,"col":7}]
```

But I get:

```
["error",{"start":{"line":1,"col":0},"end":{"line":1,"col":3},"type":"type","sub":[],"valid":true,"message":"Error: Unbound constructor Foo"}]
```

Which makes sense, because I haven't actually mentioned which file I'm querying, nor does the query ( https://github.com/ocaml/merlin/blob/master/doc/dev/OLD-PROTOCOL.md#type-checking ) allow me to.

**E** I should mention that I'm using BuckleScript, not `ocamlc`, and also `ocamlc -i` only works if I specify not just my module but all its module dependencies; I'm looking for something that automatically manages those dependencies.

Comment: FYI, `-i` compiler option shows you the signature of the source, i.e. `ocamlc -i foo.ml`.

Comment: @camlspotter updated question to clarify 

Comment: You could load your project into the toplevel and `#show Foo` (or `#mod_use "foo.ml"`), which will print the signature.

Comment: @gsg this won't work for BuckleScript modules since they won't be compiled to normal OCaml object files.

Answer (score 2):

One way to get Merlin to output the inferred signature of a module is to feed it a sequence of commands (as described in its protocol at https://github.com/ocaml/merlin/blob/master/doc/dev/OLD-PROTOCOL.md#type-checking ) that first define the module and then ask for its signature. We can prepare a temporary file that contains this sequence of commands and give it to Merlin as standard input.

The tricky parts are: wrapping the input with the correct commands; escaping double-quote characters in the input file so they don't mix with Merlin's input format; and unwrapping the output to discard Merlin's protocol formatting. Here are the crucial commands:

```
it=~/tmp/it

echo '["tell","start","end","module It = struct' >$it
sed 's/"/\\"/g' ${1%i} >>$it
echo ' end let () = ()"]' >>$it
echo '["type","expression","It","at","end"]' >>$it

ocamlmerlin <$it | sed -e '/^\["return",true\]$/d' -e 's/^\["return","sig *//' -e 's/ *end"\]$//' -e 's/\\"/"/g' -e 's/\\n/\
/g' | sed -e '/^ *$/d' -e 's/^  //'
```

Caveats:

- The above assumes a Unix-y system with `touch` and `sed`, and also `ocamlmerlin` in the command path
- Merlin doesn't preserve OCaml attributes (`[@...]`) in its output
- Works only for OCaml syntax, but can be adapted to Reason syntax

A more full-fledged script can be found at https://gist.github.com/yawaramin/b86557ae81cbd019fcb9e071abe594de .